# declare variable inside brackets of executed method

Tags: c#

by default, variable is defined before method execution, like:

```
DateTime myDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out myDate)){
   .....
}
```

Can we achieve inline declaration (and that variable could be used outside), like :

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out DateTime myDate)){
   .....
}
```

Is there any way to achieve that in earlier than C#7 ?

Comment: Because it would go out of scope before you could use it inside the if block

Comment: Not quite right, C#7 supports that exact behavior.

Comment: @Waescher Is there any way to achieve that in earlier than C#7 ?

Comment: @T.Todua Unfortunately not, no. VS (and the compiler ofc) needs to be able to interpret the syntax. This is what the C#7 language specs are there for.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve inline declaration if you make use of C# 7. Unfortunately in previous versions of C# this is not supported. For further info please have a look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/).

Comment: Is there any solution earlier than C#7 ?

Comment: @T.Todua as I am aware of, nope.

Answer (score 3):

It is supported with [`c# 7`](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2017/03/23/inline-out-variables-and-ref-locals-and-returns-in-csharp7/)

C# 7 has extended the way these modifiers can be used:

- out variables can be declared inline and used in the outer scope
- ref can be used for locals and return values from functions

Official documentation - **[`What’s New in C# 7.0`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)**

Comment: Is there any solution earlier than C#7 ?

Comment: No , there is no alternative with earlier version